# Transferring Domains from Gworkspace/sqaurespace to Godaddy. DNS Error ede6, site doesnt work, missing emails from certain providers i.e outlook

Tags: domains, dns, godaddy, nameserver, dnssec

as above, recently transferred domains for my small business from google domains created feb, now sold to sqaurespace, and am in a pickle.
Emails are not being recieved from certain providers, i.e cant recieve from outlook, they bounce back & Website is up for 2 people tested on iphone but not on our computers or android, etc. Sending emails is fine. We use Gmail & Google workspace to send and recieve emails.

We used google workspace to set up domain in Feb 23.
Transferred to Godaddy on 1/FEB
Google said this:

"Hello ,

It is an issue with your NAME SERVERS (NS) records. Once the NS and MX records are updated properly, you will be able to receive the emails. It needs to be updated from the Godaddy end.

Once the records were updated it would be reflected in the link below:

[https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#MX/cox*******.co.nz"](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#MX/cox*******.co.nz%22)

Godaddy tried some fixes but seemed pretty useless. Keep asking us to wait for it to propogate, its been 7 days.

Trying to send an email from outlook to myself on the domain - Returns this:
[image: Outlook]

Here's what it looks like from Godaddy's End:[image: Settings]
[image: Godaddy settings 2]

Website looks like this as well: [image: Website error]

DNS Debugger looks like this: [image: DNS Debugger]

Please help me, she's tough out there.
Happy to provide URL if needed.
Godaddy and google support aren't getting me anywhere. Just want my site and emails to work!

Comment: I'm not sure we can help you without the domain - please add that as a comment below.

Comment: Hi Dan, thank you for the reply. The domain is coxferguson.co.nz

Comment: Update from google:

Thank you for contacting Google Workspace Support.  I hope this email finds you well.

After investigation with the internal team, It is informed that there is no issue at the workspace end. The emails that reach your domain servers were getting delivered properly. If the email sent from a particular sender hit your domain servers then that would be reflected in the email log search. However, it seems your domain DNS records were not propagated properly. It needs to be verified at your host provider.

Reference link: https://www.whatsmydns.net/#MX/coxferguson.co.nz

Comment: It's unclear if you're still having issues or not. It appear your MX records needed to be updated and DNS propagation can take several days - sometimes longer for some ISPs. The reference link provided shows it's now propagated world-wide, the red X's are common (i.e., using `google.com` in replace of your domain will still show some). If you're still having issues, run through the steps here to double-check your DNS and MX records: [GoDaddy: Activate Gmail for Google Workspace](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33353?hl=en)